# Mongoose/MongoDB: Can I update a document if I have a reference to it already without a query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I perform `db.collection.findOne( {query}`... In the callback, if I successfully find an object, I want to modify one of it's properties...

```
,function(err, obj){
    //is there a better way to do this since I already have a reference to the object? Searching the docs always gives me db.collection APIs
    db.collection.update( {_id: obj._id }, { modifications}, function(err, obj){ ... }
}
```

Comment: The real question should be *"why are you even doing the `.findOne()`?"*. If your **only** intention is to "update a property" then you should instead **only** be doing the `.update()`. In that way it's **one** trip to the database, rather than **two**. So I think you need to "reverse" your thinking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subject includes `mongoose` so I guess you are using mongoose.
So there are two good ways you can do that (of course there are much more ways to do that):

1. Use `findOneAndUpdate`

   ```
   model.findOneAndUpdate(query, {modifications}, function(err, obj) { //callback } )
   ```

[read more about it here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

2. your returned `obj` in the callback is a mongoose model, so you can modify it and `save` it:

   ```
   function(err, obj){
       obj.some_field = 'blabla';

       obj.save();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

You can also use the [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) to use a single query. If nothing is found, nothing should be modified.